# Two Columns Submenu Issue

Tags: css, wordpress

Trying to design a sub menu that isnt terrible. Have the following CSS but its causing me a few problems currently.

CSS:

```
/*Sub Menu Columns*/
.sub-menu { 
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,250px);
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
}
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li {
    clear: initial;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
} 
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <ul id="menu-desktop-menu" class="et-menu nav"><li class="first-level et_pb_menu_page_id-home menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-20"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Main Menu 1</a></li>
    <li class="sub-menu-columns et_pb_menu_page_id-1143 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-1268"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">OUR SERVICES</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-25803 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25857"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-25734 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25858"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-25984 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25993"><a href="REDACTED"  data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 3</a></li>
        <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-25994 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25999"><a href="REDACTED"  data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 4</a></li>
        <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-26006 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26166"><a href="REDACTED"  data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 5</a></li>
        <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-26021 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-26021 current_page_item menu-item-26165"><a href="REDACTED"  aria-current="page" data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 6</a></li>
        <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-26027 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26164"><a href="REDACTED"  data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 7</a></li>
        <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-26031 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26163"><a href="REDACTED"  data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 8</a></li>
        <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-26122 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26162"><a href="REDACTED"  data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 9</a></li>
        <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-26142 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26161"><a href="REDACTED"  data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 10</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="first-level et_pb_menu_page_id-1473 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1529"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Main Menu 3</a></li>
    <li class="first-level et_pb_menu_page_id-24926 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25343"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Main Menu 4</a></li>
    <li class="first-level et_pb_menu_page_id-1576 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24917"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Main Menu 5</a></li>
    <li class="hide-desktop second-level et_pb_menu_page_id-1304 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24869"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Main Menu 6</a></li>
    <li class="hide-desktop second-level et_pb_menu_page_id-24870 menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24870"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Main Menu 7</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Issue 1:

I would like all submenu items to be on one line if at all possible. I have messed with margins, widths and gaps for this but each time, the menu itself gets wider but the submenu items do not resolve to single lines

Issue 2:

Currently the submenu has an odd white line that interferes with the main menu. I would like to add padding to this to move the sub menu inline with the main menus bottom edge.

Issue 3:

Finally, not added here is that I would like to add a seperator white line to each submenu item (border) however attempts at doing so have resulted poorly. I do not want to add a white line to items Fiver or Ten in this case. All efforts to avoid this have been unsuccessful.

[image: This is the bad Version Currently]

Below is my ideal on how I would like the menu to appear in the end.

[image]

As always, your help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using floats for layout like this when you have grid there?

Comment: Post your relevant HTML please.

Comment: Hi, and apologies. Im using Wordpress and Divi rather than my own HTML which further complicates things. As you can tell with the floats, im not confident with what im doing here

Comment: Go into your inspector in your browser... Do this by right clicking on the menu element in your browser and select **inspect**. You will see the HTML there, open the section of the HTML that corresponds with this issue, copy and paste it into your question ;)

Comment: Have added in to the main topic as needed :) Cheers for the guidance on that

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example getting your desired result best I could with the HTML and CSS you provided.

### **Note on ***floats*** in CSS today:**

***This may be a bit subjective***, but I think you'll find many that agree on this basic concept in regards to floating elements.

*[MDN: The float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) CSS property places an element on the left or right side of its container, allowing text and inline elements to wrap around it. **The element is removed from the normal flow of the page**, though still remaining a part of the flow*

There are far too many tools in today's CSS for aligning elements inline whether column or row orientation to use floats. Floats should IMHO only be used when you wish to have text ***float*** ***around*** an *image*, *video* or *iframe* or other similarly positioned element that you want text to ***flow*** around.

### To your question:

~ Here is my attempt to recreate your desired output using the limited amount of CSS you provided.

You can use [***flex box***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) ***(display: flex)*** items as your child elements ***list-items*** and then use a pseudo element [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) to style the break in between your list items. By removing the floats and adding `display: flex;` on the ***list-items***, you are allowing them to take up the remainder of the parent elements width *minus any gap or padding on width -> **X** axis*.  I also added [`flex-grow: 1;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) on the children so they will grow ***equally*** to fill the width they inherit.

As for the pseudo element `li:after` along with the ***odd*** and ***even*** selectors we use them to add a `:not(li.last-of-type)` and `:not(li:nth-of-type(9))` so the last two **spacers** between ***list-items*** do not render. [MDN: ":not()"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) - [MDN: ":nth-of-type()"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) - [MDN: ":last-of-type()"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)

```css
/*Sub Menu Columns*/

body {
  background-color: #21263A;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(odd):not(.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-of-type(9))::after,
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(even):not(.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:last-of-type)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: .2rem;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: grid;
  /* changes static px width to fractional 1fr */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  /* max content here will expand your width to 
     fit the max amount of content */
  width: max-content;
}


/* make all the sub-menu list-items display: flex
   so we can control their alignment properties */

.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li {
  clear: initial;
  display: flex;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: .5rem .2rem;
}

.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-right: 10px;
  /* justify content to center, can also use flex-start or flex-end */
  justify-content: center;
  /* flex-grow: 1 on both child elements so they 
     equally fill in their widest elements width */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(even) {
  /* justify content to center, can also use flex-start or flex-end */
  justify-content: center;      
  /* flex-grow: 1 on both child elements so they 
     equally fill in their widest elements width */
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-desktop-menu" class="et-menu nav">
  <li class="first-level et_pb_menu_page_id-home menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-20"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Main Menu 1</a></li>
  <li class="sub-menu-columns et_pb_menu_page_id-1143 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-1268"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">OUR SERVICES</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-25803 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25857"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 1</a></li>
      <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-25734 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25858"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Here is longer than anticipated list-item</a></li>
      <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-25984 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25993"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 3</a></li>
      <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-25994 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25999"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 4</a></li>
      <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-26006 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26166"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 5</a></li>
      <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-26021 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-26021 current_page_item menu-item-26165"><a href="REDACTED" aria-current="page" data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 6</a></li>
      <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-26027 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26164"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">This is a very long list-item here</a></li>
      <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-26031 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26163"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 8</a></li>
      <!-- if more items are added, you will have to go into css file 
           and change the second to last item 
           :not(:li:nth-of-type(this-items-index))::after -->
      <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-26122 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26162"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Yet another ridiculously super long list-item that will dynamically grow</a></li>
      <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-26142 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26161"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Menu Item 10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="first-level et_pb_menu_page_id-1473 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1529"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Main Menu 3</a></li>
  <li class="first-level et_pb_menu_page_id-24926 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25343"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Main Menu 4</a></li>
  <li class="first-level et_pb_menu_page_id-1576 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24917"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Main Menu 5</a></li>
  <li class="hide-desktop second-level et_pb_menu_page_id-1304 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24869"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Main Menu 6</a></li>
  <li class="hide-desktop second-level et_pb_menu_page_id-24870 menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24870"><a href="REDACTED" data-ps2id-api="true">Main Menu 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is so close to perfect. Border items are spot on, only issue is text is still going over two lines still. Other than that, this is amazing :) Also, thank you so much for educating me on this and how you get to the solution.

Comment: You need to increase your max-width of your parent element. I believe you are setting that in your grid display for columns.

Comment: Try changing the following line: `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 250px);` to `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);`, you may need to play around with that width to get the right width that looks good for the content you are passing into those elements. Also add the following for your `sub-menu` as well: `width: max-content`

Comment: I have updated the answer with added `width: max-content:` and `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);` also a bit of x-axis padding on the content as well.

Comment: have added all of this in as needed. Text still refuses to go across 1 line, I can work around this by just grouping the two liners next to each other so it doesnt look so naff. The background for the submenu now doesnt expand either so its coming up short but can work around that by setting .nav width

Comment: Oh, and the submenu hasnt dropped inline with the main menu either but thats too much hassle to deal with atm. So sorry for all of this but thanks for what youve done! its incredible